# Implementing a sliding window(cube) to crop a point cloud in Python

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, point-clouds, sliding-window

I want to crop a very large point cloud. I only have np.array of 3D coordinates of these points

```
[[  165.  1958.  3832.]
 [  165.  1958.  3833.]
 [  165.  1958.  3834.]
 ...
 [ 6090. 11602.  9475.]
 [ 6090. 11602.  9476.]
 [ 6090. 11602.  9477.]]
```

I was considering to implement a sliding window(cube) technique. Basically I assumed these `N` points are in large volume and  I want to iterate sliding window inside of this large volume to crop subvolumes with a certain number of points.

For example if I have a cube with a fixed size of `20x20x20` and my sliding cube starts at `[160,1958,3213]` I want to have indices of points `[  165.  1958.  3832.]` and `[  165.  1958.  3833.]`  which is `[0,1]` In next iteration my sliding cube will start at  `[180,1978,3233]`

Since `N` is very large I can't create a new volume and occupy indices of point cloud and brute-force my way. Is there any efficient way to do this in Python? I am open to new ideas as well.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a cube starting at `[x,y,z]` with side `s` and you want to find all points `[a,b,c]` in your array  such that `x <= a <= x+s`, `y <= b <= y+s` and `z <= c <= z+s`? How does the "sliding window" work?

Comment: I am sorry my example wasn't clear enough. I edited my question.

Comment: Now the sliding cube is clearer. Please, explain what memory constraints you have.